# Escaping spaces in bash command line output

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to output a list of files, which will be piped into another command, but the spaces need to be escaped. I've got this far:

```
find ./ | grep ".mkv$" | awk '{ print "\"" $0 "\"" }'
```

Which outputs something along the lines of:

```
"/dir/File One.mkv"
"/dir/File Two.mkv"
"/File Three blah blah.mkv"
```

But I need it to output:

```
"/dir/File\ One.mkv"
"/dir/File\ Two.mkv"
"/File\ Three\ blah\ blah.mkv"
```

Is there a simple command/regex I can add to my command?

Comment: try with `find ./ | grep ".mkv$" | awk '{ print "\"" $0 "\"" }' | sed 's/ /\\ /g'`

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks :D ... Post it as an answer :D

Comment: You can combine the `find` and `grep` thus:   `find . -name \*.mkv | awk ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use sed to substitute some backslashes before spaces

**command**

```
find ./ | grep ".mkv$" | awk '{ print "\"" $0 "\"" }' | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```

**output**

```
"./dir/File\ Two.mkv"
"./dir/File\ One.mkv"
"./File\ Three\ blah\ blah.mkv"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `grep`, `awk` etc here. Just find the files you want using `-name` parameter and optionally use `sed` to escape the spaces:

```
find . -name '*.mkv' -printf "'%p'\n" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/\\&/g'
'./dir/File\ One.mkv'
'./dir/File\ Two.mkv'
'./File\ Three\ blah\ blah.mkv'
```